# Using mutate with map2 and exec instead of invoke_map

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, rlang

This example in "R for Data Science" uses `invoke_map` which is now retired.

```
sim <- tribble(
  ~f, ~params,
  "runif", list(min = -1, max = 1),
  "rnorm", list(sd = 5),
  "rpois", list(lambda = 10)
)

sim %>% 
  mutate(sim = invoke_map(f, params, n = 10))
```

If I extract the columns separately then it works with `map2` and `exec`

```
map2(sim$f, sim$params, function(fn, args) exec(fn, !!!args, n = 10))
```

However, I cannot get `mutate` to work with `map2` and `exec`

```
sim %>% 
  mutate(sim = map2(f, params, function(fn, args) exec(fn, !!!args, n = 10)))
```

I get the error "Error: Can't splice an object of type closure because it is not a vector"

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!!!` operator takes precedence over the creation of the anonymous function. As a result, it evaluates `args` **immediately** in the scope of the data frame and, when it finds no such column, in the global scope. One solution is to move the function definition outside the `map2` call:

```
myfun <- function(fn, args) exec(fn, !!!args, n = 10)

sim %>% 
  mutate(sim = map2(f, params, myfun))        # Now works
```

Another solution is to concatenate the function name and all parameters into a single list, and then pass that list to `exec` with its [domain lifted](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/lift.html):

```
sim %>%
    mutate(temp = map2(f, params, c, n=10),
           sim  = map(temp, lift(exec)),
           temp = NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies somewhere in `exec` or, more specifically,  the big-bang (`!!!`) part, which for some reason tries to splice not your variable `args`, but the function `base::args` (thus, the error message you receive). You can try renaming `args` to something else and you'll get a different error:

```
> sim %>% 
  mutate(sim = map2(f, params, .f = function(fn, x) {exec(fn, !!!x, n = 10)}))
Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
  object 'x' not found
```

I must say I'm not in deep enough to disentangle this, but if you need a quick resolution, use `do.call` instead and pull `n = 10` into the args using `c`:

```
sim %>% 
  mutate(sim = map2(f, params, .f = function(fn, args) {do.call(fn, c(args, n = 10))}))
```